# Did the US stop using the U-2 spy plane for USSR after the shoot-down event in 1960?

Tags: soviet-union, cold-war

[The shoot-down of Powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1960_U-2_incident) is a famous event in the history of modern military.

Did US stop using U-2 afterwards on USSR?

It is known that this event stimulated the US spy satellite program.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is (partially) answered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2#Restructuring)

> On 4 January 1961, the CIA U-2 reconnaissance effort, which was formerly known as CHALICE, was redesignated IDEALIST.[104](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2#cite_note-104)This program codeword by the end of the decade was being used to describe the U.S. reconnaissance along the Chinese coastline, while Taiwanese missions into the Chinese country would be known as the IDEALIST program[105](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2#cite_note-cia1969-105)

Also see

> Although Eisenhower refused to end the U-2 program, it was quickly overtaken by new technology, as satellite images replaced aerial photographs.  *[state.gov](https://history.state.gov/milestones/1953-1960/u2-incident)*

I don't see any evidence of U-2 flights over the Soviet Union or Russia, but absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Comment: The question was about using the U-2 *on the USSR*. Sorties on China and Cuba don't answer the question.

Comment: Thank you ! I will edit.